# React modules couldn't be hot updated

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-hot-loader

Im building a web application using react-router and material-ui. i recently notice that react hot loader has updated and ive some issues while using ho loader with material-ui. when ever i use it with react router the hot loader wont work for the children components.
here is my code of index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader'
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory,IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
import routes from './routes';

injectTapEventPlugin();

const App = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);

render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'));

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./components/App', () => {
    const NextApp = require('./components/App').default;
    render(
      <AppContainer>
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <NextApp/>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
      </AppContainer>
      ,
      document.getElementById('app')
    );
  });
}
```

here my App Component

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from './Home';
import About from './About/AboutPage.react';
import NavigationBar from './navigation/navigationBar.react';



class App extends React.Component{
   render(){
     return(
       <div>
        <NavigationBar/>
        {this.props.children}
       </div>
     );
   }
}

export default App;
```

the routes file

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory,IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import App1 from './components/App';
import NavigationBar from './components/navigation/navigationBar.react';
import greetings from './components/Login/greetings';


export default (
     <Route path="/" component={App1}>
       <IndexRoute component={greetings}/>
     </Route>
);
```

when ever i make any changes to the child components the browser console gives a warning saying
**the following modules couldn't be hot updated: (Full reload needed)
This is usually because the modules which have changed (and their parents) do not know how to hot reload themselves. See http://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement-with-webpack.html for more details.** 
Any particular reason why im getting this and how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're also wrapping the initial render with the react-hot-loader's AppContainer component as well. Like this:

```
const App = () => (
  <AppContainer>
    <MuiThemeProvider>
      <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  </AppContainer>
);
```

Also, i'm not seeing your webpack config so make sure you also include `react-hot-loader/patch` for your very first entry like this for example:

```
entry: [
  'react-hot-loader/patch',
  `webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:${config.port}`,
  'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
  './src/index.jsx'
],
```

If you also have a `.babelrc` file, make sure to include it as one of your plugins like this:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    "es2015",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react-hot-loader/babel",
    "transform-decorators-legacy"
  ]
}
```